# explanation on python slice function output

Tags: python, slice

```py
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(a[8:-10:-2])
```

output i get
`[9, 7, 5, 3, 1]`

can anyone explain the logic and breakdown of python code output. I m just a beginner. I asked bing ai and chat gpt for answer. According to them output should be empty list whereas according to replit, codechef and jdoodle output should be `[9, 7, 5, 3, 1]`.

Comment: _According to them output should be empty list_ - Well, that's wrong. And now you realize that AI cannot (yet) replace programmers

Answer (score 1):

When we slice a list with a[start:stop:step], the slicing will start from the start index and stop at the stop index (exclusive), taking every step element.

a[8:-10:-2] means starting from index 8 (inclusive), going up to index -10 (exclusive) in reverse order, and taking every second element.

Since we are slicing the list in reverse order, index -10 is actually equivalent to index 0 when counting from the end of the list. So the slice actually goes from index 8 to index 0 (exclusive) in reverse order, taking every second element, which gives us [9, 7, 5, 3, 1].

hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your code translates to something equivalent to this:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
index = 8
result = []
while index > len(a) + -10:
    result.append(a[index])
    index += -2
print(result)
```

Make sure you identify your `8`, `-10`, and `-2` in there.